# How to trigger event from top window to iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I know that I can trigger event only in one window. But I tried like that:
In top window I wrote:

```
jQuery('#some-popup').trigger('opened-popup');
```

And in iframe I wrote:

```
$("#some-popup", window.parent.document).bind('opened-popup', function () {
           alert('ok');
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does your iframe also contains jQuery and they are on same domain?

Comment: iframe has required jQuery and windows have one domain

Comment: I think you need to do something like frame.window.jQuery(""#popup).trigger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your frame:

instead of

```
$("#some-popup", window.parent.document).bind('opened-popup', function () {
       alert('ok');
});
```

do this

```
parent.$("#some-popup", window.parent.document).bind('opened-popup', function () {
       alert('ok');
});
```

There are two instances of jQuery in place, one for the parent and one for the frame. You're firing the event on parent's jQuery but attaching to it inside frame's own jQuery. If you attach to the parent's jQuery in child, bind (or .on()) should work.

EDIT: you may not need "window.parent.document" on bind after you attach to parent's event.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid "problems" with accessibility/visibility between windows/iframes I would suggest you [easyXDM](http://easyxdm.net/wp/)

> easyXDM is a Javascript library that enables you as a developer to
>   easily work around the limitation set in place by the Same Origin
>   Policy, in turn making it easy to communicate and expose javascript
>   API’s across domain boundaries.

Comment: I know about this lib. But I want to understand why my example doesn't work